# CSS: how do I inline 3 elements? left align, right-aligned span, left aligned

Tags: css

I want to display a table with figures aligned in a non-fixed-width font:

```
$2,280
$  300 (total discount)
$   10 (add-on fee)
```

And I'd like the dollar figures to all just be inline spans:

```
<span class='dollar'>$</span><span class='amount'>2,280</span>
<span class='dollar'>$</span><span class='amount'>300</span> (total discount)
<span class='dollar'>$</span><span class='amount'>10</span> (add-on fee)
```

But I can't quite work out the CSS to make this work. Can you help?

Comment: Why not post the CSS that you have so far?

Comment: I'm sure you have already considered this, but placing this information into a table rather than spans will give you the structure you desire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
.amount {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A72hM/

Answer (score 1):

If you know maximum amount of digits in .amount, then you can set it's display to inline-block and then set it's width.

If you don't know it's maximum width, then you should probably use an actual table instead.

Example of both methods: http://jsfiddle.net/ZbB8K/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to give span.amount a fixed width.

```
span.amount {
  width: 100px;
}
```